# Find the length of the longest contiguous sub-array in a sorted array in which the difference between the end and start values is at most k

Tags: arrays, algorithm

I have a sorted array, for example

```
[0, 0, 3, 6, 7, 8, 8, 8, 10, 11, 13]
```

Here, let's say `k = 1` so the longest sub-array is `[7, 8, 8, 8]` with `length = 4.`

As another example, consider `[0, 0, 0, 3, 6, 9, 12, 12, 12, 12]` with `k = 3.` Here the longest sub-array is `[9, 12, 12, 12, 12]` with `length = 5.`

So far, I have used a binary search algorithm `O(n log n)` which iterates from index `0 .. n - 1` and tries to find the rightmost index that satisfies our condition.

Is there a linear time algorithm to do this?

Comment: The trick to make it in linear time: assume you found the longest sub-array that starts at index i, and ends at some index j; if you increment i, you may have to update j, but the updates are always increasing. So in total the number of increases of j will not exceed n.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is a linear time algorithm. You can use two pointers technique. Here is a pseudo code:

```
R = 0
res = 0
for L = 0 .. N - 1:
    while R < N and a[R] - a[L] <= k:
        R += 1
    res = max(res, R - L)
```

It has `O(n)` time complexity because `L` and `R` are strictly increasing and each of them can be incremented only `n` times.

Why is this algorithm correct? For a fixed `L`, `R` is the index of the first element of the array such that `a[R] - a[L] > k`. That's why `R - 1` is the index of the last element that fits. The length of `[L, R - 1]` subarray is exactly `R - L`. The resulting subarray is obtained by iterating over all possible values of `L`, that is, all possibilities are checked. That's why it always finds correct answer.